# Inverse of a Matrix, with some conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra

1) If $A$ is a matrix $m\times n$, $B$ is a matrix $n\times m$ and $n<m$, then $AB$ is not invertible.

2) If $A$ is a matrix non-invertible $n\times n$, then exist a matrix $n\times n$ $B$, such that $AB=0$, but $B$ it is different from zero matrix.

Comment: I had some problems to attack this test, although I have more clear ideas about the second part.

Comment: Think in terms of linear ransformations rather than matrices.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Thank you very much for your contribution, although exercise suggests using arrays instead of linear transformations, but if I can help with this subsection would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $$rank(AB)\leq \min\{rank(A),rank(B)\}\leq n < m$$
2. Since, $A$ is not invertible, there exists $x$ in the null-space of $A$, a non-zero vector such that $Ax=0$. Now, let $B=xx^T$, then $AB=0$ and $B\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution!